# How do I make a 'surface' using pyglet, like in gamemaker studio?

Tags: python, pyglet

For a project I've been working on, I need to know how to draw to a surface/texture/whatever, that could be used as a texture for binding to a vertex list.
I'm fairly new to python/pyglet, and couldn't really find anything online.
I did find a post on here, where someone wanted to save a texture with text drawn to it, but I couldn't really figure it out.
I'm looking for some way that I could sort of go:

```
surface = new_surface(width,height)

set_target(surface)

draw_something()

reset_target()
```

Would be appreciated if someone explained how stuff like this works rather than just example code.

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. For future reference, code formatting uses the backtick (aka backquote) symbol ` (usually on the tilde ~ key) not the very similar looking single quote '. Good luck with your question & project!